# One hand was "rotated" through higher dimensions -> two right (or left hands) - Broadcast on 20th century US TV

Tags: story-identification

A scientist or technician working with (or developing) a device, transport, or portal, by accident or for reckless-research inserted his hand into the "active" area (perhaps located between two poles), causing it to be rotated through higher dimensions (?), and for the duration, or perhaps permanently, leaving him with two right or two left hands. 
    - (Online searches only returned references to various 1920s short stories, and Kant.)

This is one of the two blurry ancient mental images we could not identify after a discussion of old SF or weird tales (most likely) from a late 20th-century childhood of US broadcast television. If so, probably from syndicated series, or independent station afternoon or late-night programming (which could include an occasional UK, or english-language dubbed european or japanese production) - and much less likely something animated (because of the subject matter).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You’re describing a classic episode of *The Outer Limits* called “The Borderland,” that happens to be a favorite of mine.

> In an accident, Professor Ian Fraser encounters a magnetic field that reverses the form of living matter. When his hand is caught in the strong magnetic field, it is altered, becoming a mirror of itself. Realizing the importance of magnetic fields, Fraser theorizes that a much stronger magnetic field has the potential to open a door into another world.
>
> <sub><sup>[Pre Wikipedia - “The Borderland” episode of *The Outer Limits*, 1963](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Borderland)</sup></sub>

Comment: Can you elaborate on the contents of the link?

Comment: Super! We had gone through online episode-lists of the Outer Limits and, not surprisingly, didn't match this specific scene to the brief description "A British millionaire hires a psychic to contact his dead son; a scientist exposes her fraud."